# How to get SQLDataRoot registry setting in wix installer for 64 bit

Tags: wix

In my wix installer I have these properties to get sql data path

```
<Property Id="SQLSERVERINSTANCENAME" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlServerInstanceName" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Name="MSSQLSERVER" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="SQLSERVERDATAPATH" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="SqlServerDataPath" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQLSERVERINSTANCENAME]\Setup" Name="SQLDataRoot" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
```

but it doesn't work on 64bit Windows 2008 Server R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Win64="yes"`, this will tell the `RegistrySearch` to look in the 64-bit of the registry. Should have added this will tell the Search to only look in the 64-bit part if you need it to search both then use `Win64="$(var.Platform)"` and specify the platforms like so:

```
<!-- Define platform-specific names and locations -->
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
<?define ProductName = "$(var.ProductName)" ?>
<?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>
<?define PlatformCommonFilesFolder = "CommonFiles64Folder" ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "98CECA6F-D312-466E-B04F-088ECD9CFCA2" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define ProductName = "$(var.ProductName) (x86)" ?>
<?define Win64 = "no" ?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?define PlatformCommonFilesFolder = "CommonFilesFolder" ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "6B968607-8D3E-45AF-A590-253E54EE4617" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Regarding the registry issue I added the Win64=yes attribute but the value is empty.

Comment: Win64=yes works great. Previously I set the Execute="deferred", I removed it and it works.